How Many Unique Ways Can I Color a Regular Hexagon Using 3 Colors Without Neighboring Vertices Sharing the Same Color?
I'm trying to solve a problem involving coloring a regular hexagon. Specifically, I need to color each vertex green, red, or blue, with the restriction that no neighboring vertices can have the same color. How many different colorings are possible under these conditions?
I tried solving this but none of my methods did any help. The answer is 66 according to the answer sheet. But I don't know how can I prove it. Thank you.

What have you tried?

Fix one vertex red and an adjoining one green. Count the number of ways of completing the coloring of the 4 remaining vertices. Multiply by 6.

@MJD You method actually works. There are 12 ways of colouring the 4 remaining vertices without having neighboring vertices the same colors. And one possibility is RGRGRG which contains no Blue even though it follows the rules. So we can omit it. Now there are 11 possibilities. 11 times 6 (as you said) is 66. This is the answer given in the answer sheet. Can I know why your method works? Thank you for the solution.

For all $n$, consider all the ways to properly $3$-color the vertices of an $n$-vertex path. Let $b_n$ be the number of ways that the first and last vertex are the same color, and let $c_n$ be the number of ways the first and last vertex are different colors. We might notice that $c_n+b_n=3\cdot 2^{n-1}$.
Try to find a recurrence relation for $b_n$ and/or $c_n$. Can you express your final answer in terms of $c_n$ or $b_n$ for some $n$?
